# Does Hibernate have a caching issue in multi node environment?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, orm

This is a general question. I want to know if persistence using Hibernate has issues in multi node environments (a cluster or so) due to its caching at different levels. Are there any caching issues that slows down the performance ? If yes, how can they be prevented?
Is Spring data a better choice instead ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not clear about the point "multi node". Could you pls explain more?!

Comment: like a cluster or similar